# EXTjs: Sorting issue in extjs with number and string

Tags: extjs

I have grid in extjs, where in column the value come as 200.00 GB, 12.00 GB, 23.34 GB. When i click on sorting it not shown in proper order like Ascending or decending. Please help me how to show the combination of number and string sorting. Check Image

[image]

Comment: add some code to your question...how does your `store` look like?

Comment: How are you storing the size values? As text that would make sense, however what you really should do is store them numerically and render them as text, that could solve the sort issue.

Comment: Here is store:

Ext.define('temp.store.Device', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'temp.model.Device',
    //autoLoad: true, 
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/role.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'dis.role'
        }
    }
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-sortType

You can provide your own custom sorting method.

Comment: please check the image which i have update. I need to sort this in ASC or DESC order.

Comment: I linked you to the documentation for exactly what you want, there's even an example. Read it.

Comment: any example you have with same thing which I need?

Answer (score 0):

Try SortTypes

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.SortTypes

```
sortDir: 'ASC', sortType: 'asInt'
```